# How do I add a maintainer as an owner of a project on Gitlab

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

So, I am the owner of a project, but I can't add a maintainer as an owner as well.

It seems to be a bug.

[Unable to add maintainer as an owner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69AdX.png)

Here's what I found on it so far, *however*... it's still not answered.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28233

Answer (score 2):

This is currently discussed on [issue 44033](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44033).

This is not yet supported, but reviewed also in a [related issue with mentions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/17999).